# php: failed email (" Wrong headers and message content ")

Tags: php, email, sendmail, email-headers

i need to know why my email not sent in inbox and not able to attach file

here's my headers and message

**Headers**

```
MIME-Version: 1.0; \r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="PHP-mixed-MIME_BOUNDARY_MESSAGE_PARTS";Return-Path:mx@mozhl.com;\r\nOrganization: Shbkat.com;\r\n\r\n From: mx@shbkat.com; \r\nBcc : samarlover.php@gmail.com \r\n
```

**Message**

```
\n --PHP-mixed-MIME_BOUNDARY_MESSAGE_PARTS \r\n Content-Type:text/html;\r\n Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit \n\n I Love Egypt\r\n\r\n --PHP-mixed-MIME_BOUNDARY_MESSAGE_PARTS \r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="file.txt" ; \r\n Content-Description: file.txt; \r\n Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.txt; size=38; \r\n Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 \n\ndGhpcyBpcyBhdHRhY2hlZCBmaWxlIGluIG1haWwgZnVuY3Rpb24=
```

What is the problem and how to fix it

Comment: Missing `\r\n` before `Return-Path` header, and you have `\r\n\r\n` before the `From:` header when it should only be `\r\n`.  Also make sure your server meets requirements to send mail to large ISP's such as proper DNS records and a non-generic hostname for your IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MIME-Version: 1.0; \r\n
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="PHP-mixed-MIME_BOUNDARY_MESSAGE_PARTS";\r\n
Return-Path:mx@mozhl.com;\r\n
Organization: Shbkat.com;\r\n 
From: mx@shbkat.com; \r\n
Bcc: samarlover.php@gmail.com \r\n

\n --PHP-mixed-MIME_BOUNDARY_MESSAGE_PARTS \r\n 
Content-Type:text/html;\r\n 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit \n\n I Love Egypt\r\n\r\n --PHP-mixed-MIME_BOUNDARY_MESSAGE_PARTS \r\n 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="file.txt"; \r\n 
Content-Description: file.txt; \r\n 
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.txt; size=38; \r\n 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 \n\ndGhpcyBpcyBhdHRhY2hlZCBmaWxlIGluIG1haWwgZnVuY3Rpb24=
```